# How can I install Ubuntu to a flash drive?

Tags: installation, usb-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

How to install Ubuntu 11.10 (alpha) to a flash drive?